# Flutter - Firebase iOS connection (retrieving data)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

the connection to firebase is made successfully, however, when I try t retrieve data it shows this error:

Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnfwX.png)

Answer (score 0):

It will be fine after some time when firebase is available, Your app didn't save any backoffs before so your app is unable to obtain data for backoff cache